# Member variable with name ending in "ID" being forced into being an id by grails (hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class that has a number of member variables. Let's say it looks like this:

```
class Foo {
    String BARID
    int NUM1
}
```

When I try to persist the object, Hibernate throws an exception ("org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Provided id of the wrong type for class") complaining that my Id should be a Long type instead of a String... but I don't want BARID to actually be an id in the table, it is simply named that way for unrelated reasons. I need that variable to appear as BARID both in the object as well as in the database, for purposes of downstream compatibility (other programs require that it be called BARID).

Clearly hibernate is trying to be fancy under the hood and figure out which fields are ids. How can I tell hibernate that contrary to what it might think, this is NOT an id field?

Update: I realize the variable case is non-standard, but i would prefer to keep them as-is, unless that is the reason this is broken. (For the record, I tried switching to all lowercase "barid" and I got the exact same exception).

SOLUTION: I used Jeff's suggested solution of explicitly defining a mapping block:

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'increment'
}
```

Comment: that's a weird behavior. do you have anything in the `mapping` block of your domain class?

Comment: How about the attribute naming convention? String barId,  int num1.

Comment: Nothing in my mapping block. The reason for the unconventional naming has to do with the fact that these variables are referred to in all caps both in the input files as well as the downstream consumers. It seems silly to change the case just for this little bit of glue code.

Comment: Ok, +1 to your question :-)

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with BARID and not when you are trying to access one of these items?  `Foo.get("stringHere")` may cause something like that.

Comment: James: So far I am not trying to access the object after initializing it, other than calling .save() on it. It is at that point that I get the exception.

Comment: I would turn on sql logging with parameters and see exactly what it is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you still want the normal id field anyway so if you just add it to the domain object it should be fine I tested this on Grails 2.3.1

```
class Foo {
    Long id
    String BARID
    int NUM1
}
```

Also if you don't want to use that method you can always use the mapping block to configure the id. [Doc Here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html)

Comment: I just tried both the "Long id" solution and got the same exception as before. I also tried the mapping block change and also got the same exception. I looked and I am running Grails 2.2.4... is it possible that upgrading grails will fix this?

Comment: Let me try with 2.2.4

Comment: I tried with 2.2.4 and didn't get the error with the Long id above, in a clean grails app.

Comment: For the heck of it I tried to upgrade to 2.3.1 which of course totally broke everything. I fell back to 2.2.4 and I'm back with the same original problem.

Comment: Ah ha!!! It turns out that the problem was, I was inserting this stuff using 'run-script', but it seems that 'run-script' does not run compile (like 'run-app') and so I was never actually trying the changes that you had suggested. I have ended up going with the mapping statement and it works perfectly - thanks!